# errors with the fosuserbundle doctrine schema installation and the run command is empty

Tags: symfony, doctrine, schema, database-schema

I'm trying to install fosuserbudle and I was doing it step by step but with the documentation provided on github, I've that problem and I don't know how to fix it:

```
LENOVO@LENOVO-G500DC /c/wamp/www/pfe (master)
$ php app/console cache:clear
```

> Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput' not found in C:\w
>   amp\www\pfe\app\console on line 17
>
> Call Stack:
>       0.0000     236552   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\pfe\app\console:0

Comment: LENOVO@LENOVO-G500DC /c/wamp/www/pfe (master)
$  php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput' not found in C:\w
amp\www\pfe\app\console on line 17

Call Stack:
    0.0010     236720   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\pfe\app\console:0

Comment: can i check your composer.json some configuration is not set properly i believe

Comment: php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force --complete
 [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]

Comment: An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Aucune connexion nْa

Comment: pu مtre لtablie car lْordinateur cible lْa expressلment refusلe.
 [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Aucune connexion nْa pu مtre لtablie car lْordinateu
 r cible lْa expressلment refusلe.
 [PDOException]
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Aucune connexion nْa pu مtre لtablie car lْordinateu
 r cible lْa expressلment refusلe.
octrine:schema:update [--complete] [--dump-sql] [--force] [--em[="..."]]
 now i've that error !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

config.yml
    imports:
        - { resource: parameters.yml }
        - { resource: security.yml }
        - { resource: services.yml }

```
framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator: ~
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }

#FOS UserBundle 

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm 
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update your question, but for your error SQLSTATE[HY000][2002] it is related with your database configuration. check if the port number is correct : 3306 and the host in your parameters.yml, and if that doesnt help show us your parameters.yml

## Edit:

update your parameters.yml like this :
no brakets needed. and no comma need.

```
parameters:
  database_driver: pdo_mysql
  database_host: 127.0.0.1
  database_port: null
  database_name: symfony
  database_user: root
  database_password: null
  mailer_transport: smtp
  mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
  mailer_user: null
  mailer_password: null
  locale: en
  secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
  database_path: null
```

Comment: { parameters:
{ database_driver: pdo_mysql,
database_host: 127.0.0.1,
database_port: null, 
database_name: symfony, 
database_user: root, 
database_password: null,
mailer_transport: smtp,
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1, 
mailer_user: null,
mailer_password: null, 
locale: en, 
secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt, 
database_path: null } }

Comment: i've change the port number  to 8000 than i've return it to null , and this is what appears now 
Unable to parse at line 1 (near "{ parameters:") in C:\wamp\www\pfe\app/config\parameters.yml (which is being imported from "C:\wamp\www\pfe\app/config\config.yml").

Comment: put your parameters.yml in your question with the code tag so i can read it  there must be some typo in your parameters.yml

Comment: ah my question was ; that the doctrine:schema command does not work

Comment: what about your parameters.yml?

Comment: There is no extension able to load the configuration for "database_driver" (in C:\wamp\www\pfe\app/config\parameters.yml). Looked for namespace "database_driver", found "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "assetic", "doctrine", "sensio_framework_extra", "fos_user", "debug", "acme_demo", "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution" in C:\wamp\www\pfe\app/config\parameters.yml (which is being imported from "C:\wamp\www\pfe\app/config\config.yml") here is the error now

Comment: ok i need your config.yml too the top of it and the part of doctrine: ..... the parameters.yml is good now

Comment: i ve this now !!!! : InvalidArgumentException in ReplaceAliasByActualDefinitionPass.php line 48:
Unable to replace alias "smtp," with "swiftmailer.mailer.default.transport.real".

Comment: Ah didnt saw something important no , in parameters.yml enleve les virgule ,

Comment: yep indeed,  the probleme was with the format ;i missed the spaces , now it works normaly ..

Comment: if it solves it you can put the question as answered for others :)